Are there no limits to Javascript/Typescript file extensions?
I see people using extensions like .d.ts, .schema.ts, .route.ts, routes.ts and basically anything and everything, so I was wondering if there is no limit to the extensions you can give to your files in typescript/javascript (I've seen people do this with javascript too). So someone kindly explain what are these extensions and how to use them.
Thank you.
Edits for clarification:
In web development projects, especially when they use typescript for development, sometimes the devs use filenames that end with seemingly arbitrary extensions. Some common file extensions that I've seen are filename.d.ts, filename.route.ts, filename.actions.ts etc. Coming from a development environment where file extensions play a major role in how a sepcific file behaves (Python, Java and C), this made me very confused and I couldn't figure out:

If there was a limit to the extensions that we can give to a file name, or only a defined set of extensions are available?
Does the extensions change how the file behaves or how the file is processed by the compiler/engine? If so, please give me some examples so I can understand or link some sources for me to learn from.


.d.ts extension is intended for declaration in TypeScript see here. Regarding the others you've enounced, I don't believe they're "official", but more of a developer convention

Any filename limits or rules are imposed by the underlying operating system.

The extension of a file is always the portion after the rightmost dot.
Hence, the extension of all the files you mention is .ts. We can add as many dots in the middle of a file name as we want, only the last one matters for the extension.

So, the schema and route are added for readability/understanding what that specific file does just by reading the name of the file?

Absolutely. :) They have no other meaning than their name. I, for example, like to name my repositories "cat.repository.ts" or "dog.repository.ts". They are just TypeScript files with a name that I hope is meaningful.

This doesn't answer the question in the title. Are there limits or not and if there are limits, what are the limits.

It does because I read the actual question and not only the title. You should do the same.

This clarifies my original question, thank you for your help.
